# Nifi error : Cannot automatically terminate 'Message' relationship because a Connection already exists with this relationship

Tags: mqtt, apache-nifi

While I am making a dataflow from MQTT-FX to influxdb in Apache nifi, I am getting a error:

> Cannot automatically terminate 'Message' relationship because a
>   Connection already exists with this relationship` while configuring
>   the Consumemqtt processor.

How to resolve this ?

[image]

Comment: ConsumeMQTT's `Message` relationship is already connected to a downstream processor. You have to remove that connection before making it auto terminate. BTW, auto terminate `ConsumeMQTT` doesn't make sense. You have to connect it to some processor to actually read and process the data.

Comment: @Sivaprasanna Sethuraman I am using MQTT-Fx client for publishing/subscribing the messages and I want to store these messages in influxdb, but this error in not allowing to configure the consumemqtt processor...how to remove the downstream processor connection ?

Comment: Which processor have you connected `ConsumeMQTT` to?

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman ConsumeMQTT is connected to`PutInfluxdb` processor while its throwing that error. The message I am sending from MQTT-fx Client.

Comment: It's not throwing any error. This *alert* message is because you can't mark a relationship as auto-terminate, if it already connected to a processor for that relationship. It is connected to `PutInfluxDB` as expected, just start the `ConsumeKafka` processor.

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman `ConsumeKafka` ?? I need to connect `ConsumeMQTT` to `PutInfluxdb` ....What `ConsumeKafka` ...Do I need to add here `ConsumeKafka`too ?

Comment: My mistake. Start the `ConsumeMQTT` processor